# Can I put a dimension value under two groups simultaneously in Tableau?

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I have a dimension in my data, let's call it `Dim1` which has values of this form:

`Value1`
`Value2`
`Value1Value2`

As you can see, the value `Value1Value2` should be included under both `Value1` and `Value2`.  So ideally, my `Dim1` would only contain:

`Value1`
`Value2`

Is there any way to do some sort of grouping where a value is grouped under two groups simultaneously or otherwise any way to achieve this desired result (perhaps a calculated field)? Or is this too low-level for Tableau and can only be done on the back-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this myself with some Access-VBA code in my database on the back-end.  Here it is in case it is of use to anyone:

```
Dim splitString As String
splitString = rs![MyFieldName]
splitString = Replace(splitString, "Value1Value2", "Value1 vbCrLf Value2")
varData = Split(splitString, vbCrLf) ' Get all newline delimited fields '
```